# NulPointer Exception on FindViewById for TextView using Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When I try to change the textview(detail_text1) using an intent I get a NullPointerException.

The reason for this exception is, that the findViewById call returns null.

I already tried setting the context before but it still gives the same exception.

Please see below:

Detail Activity

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle 
                                                        savedInstanceState){

           //Activity called via intent. Inspect for forecast data.
           Intent rcvIntent = getActivity().getIntent();
           //TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_text1);
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail,container
                                                                        ,false);

                if(rcvIntent != null && rcvIntent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)){
                    String forecastStr = rcvIntent
                                         .getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

                  //View myView = (View) view.getParent();
                  //setContentView(R.layout.fragment_detail);
        //ERROR HERE!
                   TextView tv = (TextView)rootView
                                           .findViewById(R.id.detail_text1);
                    tv.setText(forecastStr);
                }

                return rootView;
            }
}
```

Fragment Detail

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.rv.myapplication
                          .DetailActivity.DetailFragment">

    <TextView
        android:text="@+id/detail_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity Detail

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.rv.myapplication.DetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rv.myapplication" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.rv.myapplication.MyActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Let me know it there is more code needed.

Thanks all!

**Imports by Request**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Comment: looks good, can you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you post your imports? You may have inadvertently imported android.R - Which can cause this NPE.

Comment: Package names are not same from maifest and xml.  modify once and clean and rebuild

Comment: @blackbelt Already did that and Invalidate Caches and Restart. Didn't Help.

Comment: Is DetailActivity a Fragment?

Comment: @Ice yes because `onCreateView`

Comment: To get data from activity to fragment, use getarguments() not getintent(). U can try by change this once.

Comment: Usually a Fragment shouldn't appears in the manifest:
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.rv.myapplication.MyActivity" />
        </activity>

and shouldn't called using Intent

Comment: @Ice see above.  It's an activity.

Comment: However if you need to send data from an Activity to Fragment you should evaluate as good practice the Bundle to set an arguments for Fragment and onAttach() method of fragment reading the data using getArguments()

Comment: I mess... I saw onCreateView() so I supposed was a Fragment as you told me before, but now you wrote me is an Activity. No problem

Comment: @Ice sorry i told you it is a fragment because of that mistake

Comment: @Ice so far i have never seen anybody use that method to create view, all i have seen is `onCreate` and `setContentView`

Comment: Ok, so if it is an Activity, take care about the method onCreateView() as sown at Android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)

Comment: @mmlooloo You Totally right! That's reason why I mess reading the code!!! However for API level 1 an Activity can have an onCreateView() but not used as shown by TheCodingCat but in this way
public View onCreateView (String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

Take care TheCodingCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you problem is here:

in Activity lifecycle onCreateView is:

```
public View onCreateView (View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

and

```
onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

but in fragment lifecycle onCreatView is

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

so you mess up those.

so what you should do?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_detail);  

           Intent rcvIntent = getActivity().getIntent();

                if(rcvIntent != null && rcvIntent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)){
                    String forecastStr = rcvIntent
                                         .getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

       TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_text1);                                       
                    tv.setText(forecastStr);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by lifecycle and how it affects what I'm trying to do?

Comment: lifecycle callback method are those you override to make your activity and your fragment run correctly for example what will happen when your activity is going to create? what layout it must use and so on, see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle

Comment: and also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html for functions that begin by `on` for example `onCreate` `onDestroy` `onStart`

Comment: look at the diagram that is drawn to understand perfectly at  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I tried this but it still gives me a nullexception.

Comment: first remove all of `tools:context` from two layouts you have post

Comment: and tell exactly where you got `nullexception`

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_text1); tv is null so I can't setText().  I placed this on onCreate exactly as you mentioned.

Comment: clean and build again if there exist that means in `R.layout.fragment_detail` there is no `detail_text1` so check your names exactly, i can not find your bugs because i do not have your project and i think it is not so hard to find it.

Answer (score 1):

If your error is in the line:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text1);
```

It means that `rootView` is `null`, which also means that the real problem is that the `inflate()` method is returning `null` for some reason. please provide the error log from the Logcat